# Explain the output of realpath

Tags: command-line, files, path

I am trying to use the command line to return the absolute path to a file. I read that there are multiple ways to go about this, namely the `realpath`, `readpath -f`, and `locate` commands.

None of these worked out for me. As shown below, if I was in the main directory and searched for a file some arbitrary number of directories below it would only return the current directory with the file at the end. Likewise, I would be some distance down and search for a file in the main directory and be returned with my current directory followed by the file.

```
[seisemann@localhost ~]$ cd uno
[seisemann@localhost uno]$ ls
dos  first
[seisemann@localhost uno]$ cd dos
[seisemann@localhost dos]$ ls
second
[seisemann@localhost dos]$ cd
[seisemann@localhost ~]$ realpath second
/home/seisemann/second
[seisemann@localhost ~]$
```

My question is, why is this happening? Why aren't any of these commands working as expected?

Edit:
    What I want to know is if there is a command that will return the path to a file wherever it should be found, if it exists.
For some context, currently I am opening a directory in a python script and trying to execute a terminal command to get the paths to the files within the folder. I don't want to hard code the path since this needs to be semi-portable, but the commands that I was able to find are not doing what I expected them to.

Comment: What is it you are expecting ?, please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/286939/edit) your question with your expectations.

Comment: Do you happen to have a file called `second` in your home directory?

Comment: Please repeat the above commands, but replace `ls` with `ls -la`, and post the results of that.  Also, do an `ls -la` from your home directory, `~` (and BTW, it's called ***your home directory***, not "the main directory").  And also try harder to explain what you are trying to accomplish and what you expect the commands to do. P.S. I believe that it is highly unlikely that `locate` will be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If the file does not exist *realpath* just appends the filename to the current path.

```
cd /tmp
touch foo
mkdir empty
cd empty
realpath nothing_here
ln -s /tmp/foo nothing_here
realpath nothing_here
```

First it results in `/tmp/empty/nothing_here` as the file does not exist,
after the `ln` it prints `/tmp/foo`

according to the man page this seems to be correct:

> Print the resolved absolute file name; all but the last component must exist

so to find the real path of second using realpath you should use one valid path for it. It does not search for your files!

```
realpath ~/uno/dos/second
```

should do the trick